# What is meant by "built" regarding the Vineyard card?

Tags: 7-wonders

On the recommendation of a friend, I picked up 7 Wonders, and two other friends and I played our first game a few nights ago.  When one of my friends played *Vineyard*, we had a lengthy discussion of what the rules meant.

> The card is worth 1 coin per brown card **built** in the player's city AND in the two neighboring cities.
>   *Clarification: The brown cards built on in the neighboring cities on the same turn as the Vineyard are counted.*

Emphasis mine.  The key discussion is what is meant by built.  In this context, it's ambiguous as to whether "built" is in the past tense or the future tense.  During our first game, we came to the conclusion that it must mean future.  We arrived at this conclusion through the misconception that the players would be paying the Vineyard owner instead of the owner drawing the funds from the central bank.  By the second game, we had forgotten our misconception, and decided that built must be past tense, as there are far too few  resource cards in the second age, and none in the third, to make Vineyard worth while.  We didn't really worry about it that much, since I discarded Vineyard on the last turn.

So, what is actually meant?  Do I collect a coin for every brown card I have in play right now, as well as a coin for the brown cards my neighbors have in play at the end of this turn?  Do I disregard existing brown cards, and collect a coin when my neighbors or I play a new brown card?  Or is it everything - do I instantly collect a coin for existing brown cards, as well as a coin for each future brown cards when they're played?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get **1 coin per brown card that already exists, including brown cards built by your neighbors in the same round.** Note that brown resources built into player boards do not count for this.

You do not get any coins for brown cards built in future rounds. All Age cards that provide coins provide them immediately.

Answer (score 5):

You get 1 coin per brown card built in your city and in the two neighboring cities, **including** any built on the same turn as the Vineyard.

The clarification is to remind you to count cards built this turn, which is different than the normal rules, like commerce, which don't make resources built this turn available until the next turn.

The [rules](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_US_WHITE.pdf) specify that you only count cards, and any resources on the Wonder boards don't count (top page 8)

> Clarification: The resources produced by the board are not considered to be cards.